# How to query same objects next to ech other from table with 2d coordinates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lately, I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out the problem of selecting a group of items with the same attribute and which are next to each other.
I have such columns:

Lp.  attr.  x corr. y coor width height 
Here are sample data (x,y are coordinates of left bottom cornerr of rectangle):

```
CREATE TABLE example_rect (
id int NULL,
attr varchar(5) NULL,
x numeric(5,2) NULL,
y numeric(5,2) NULL,
height numeric(5,2) NULL,
width numeric(5,2) NULL
);

INSERT INTO example_rect (id,attr,x,y,height,width) VALUES 
(1,'A',0.36,43.60,7.15,5.72)
,(2,'A',0.50,35.60,7.15,4.65)
,(3,'A',0.88,26.75,6.00,4.25)
,(4,'B',5.50,36.00,6.75,5.15)
,(5,'B',6.25,43.35,8.40,5.51)
,(6,'C',6.60,25.95,7.80,4.93)
,(7,'B',11.50,36.00,6.75,5.15)
,(8,'B',12.25,43.35,8.40,5.51)
,(9,'C',12.60,25.95,7.80,4.93)
,(10,'E',17.19,34.67,8.08,5.53)
,(11,'D',18.45,25.92,7.83,5.18)
,(12,'A',18.78,44.04,6.71,4.45)
,(13,'E',23.19,34.67,8.08,5.53)
,(14,'A',23.78,44.04,6.71,4.45)
,(15,'D',24.50,27.88,5.87,3.00)
,(16,'B',28.50,44.00,6.75,5.15)
,(17,'D',28.50,27.88,5.87,3.00)
,(18,'E',29.18,34.71,8.04,5.58)
,(19,'D',33.50,27.88,5.87,2.99)
,(20,'B',34.50,44.00,6.75,5.15)
,(21,'E',35.19,34.71,8.04,5.58)
,(22,'D',37.50,27.88,5.87,2.99)
,(23,'B',40.42,46.07,4.68,3.11)
,(24,'E',41.33,32.76,5.99,3.35)
,(25,'D',41.50,25.90,5.85,2.98)
,(26,'J',41.56,40.29,4.46,2.85)
,(27,'B',43.42,46.07,4.68,3.11)
,(28,'E',45.33,32.76,5.99,3.35)
,(29,'B',45.42,40.07,4.68,3.11)
,(30,'D',45.50,25.83,5.75,3.00)
,(31,'B',47.42,46.07,4.68,3.11)
,(32,'B',49.42,40.07,4.68,3.11)
,(33,'E',49.45,32.75,6.00,3.14)
,(34,'D',49.50,25.83,5.75,3.00)
,(35,'F',50.56,46.05,4.46,2.83)
,(36,'B',53.44,32.25,6.50,3.13)
,(37,'D',53.50,25.83,5.75,3.00)
,(38,'J',53.56,40.29,4.46,2.85)
,(39,'F',54.56,46.05,4.46,2.83)
,(40,'B',57.44,32.25,6.50,3.13)
,(41,'D',57.50,25.83,5.75,3.00)
,(42,'J',57.56,40.29,4.46,2.85)
,(43,'F',58.57,46.29,4.46,2.83)
,(44,'E',60.97,26.85,4.90,2.06)
,(45,'B',61.42,40.07,4.68,3.11)
,(46,'E',61.47,33.13,4.62,3.05)
,(47,'F',61.57,46.29,4.46,2.83)
,(48,'E',63.97,26.85,4.90,2.06)
,(49,'F',64.56,46.29,4.46,2.83)
,(50,'B',65.42,40.07,4.68,3.11)
,(51,'E',65.47,33.13,4.62,3.05)
,(52,'D',67.50,27.07,4.68,2.99)
,(53,'F',68.56,46.29,4.46,2.83)
,(54,'E',69.44,32.75,6.00,3.14)
,(55,'E',69.50,40.13,4.62,3.05)
,(56,'D',71.50,27.07,4.68,2.99)
,(57,'F',72.66,46.29,4.46,2.83)
,(58,'E',73.50,40.13,4.62,3.05)
,(59,'E',74.47,33.13,4.62,3.05)
,(60,'C',75.15,26.07,5.68,3.91)
,(61,'F',75.66,46.29,4.46,2.83)
,(62,'E',77.62,38.24,4.51,2.73)
,(63,'E',78.47,33.13,4.62,3.05)
,(64,'F',79.57,43.02,8.73,2.88)
,(65,'C',80.15,26.07,5.68,3.91)
,(66,'E',80.62,38.24,4.51,2.73)
,(67,'F',83.15,43.01,8.74,1.93)
,(68,'E',83.47,33.13,4.62,3.05)
,(69,'E',83.92,38.06,4.69,2.18)
,(70,'C',84.26,26.78,4.97,3.47)
,(71,'C',85.90,43.86,7.89,2.18)
,(72,'G',87.25,35.23,6.52,3.54)
,(73,'H',88.00,26.00,6.50,4.00)
,(74,'C',88.90,43.86,7.89,2.18)
,(75,'B',91.05,35.23,6.52,4.18)
,(76,'C',91.06,42.92,8.83,1.92)
,(77,'I',92.19,26.70,5.06,3.65)
,(78,'C',93.06,42.92,8.83,1.92)
;
```

When I visualize these items I receive something like (where each color is different attribute A, B, C etc.):

[image: visualisation of rectangles in 2d]

What I want to achieve is to select only rows which create groups with the same attribute. Or other words, in the end, I want to know the number of the same rectangles in the direct neighbor of each of rectangle.

I have to implement a solution in SQL/T-SQL.

Maybe somebody already encountered such problem and could suggest some solution.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions,

Comment: I think you'll have to explain a bit more. Can you provide some sample data? How are you creating the visualization?

Comment: that is a nice visual that you have posted. But I can't visualize your problem. How about some table schema, sample data and required result ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the additional questions you are perfectly right that it wasn't clear without sample data. I created the visualization using matplotlib module.

Comment: 2 Questions: How do you determine determine "direct neighbour" (like sides or Above as well?). And based on your output, can you edit it and also show us what your desired output would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several important details that would have a significant impact on this answer. Some of them have already been asked in the comments.

1. What defines a direct neighbor? For now I am assuming you just want neighbors on the horizontal axis.
2. Given that there are rectangles of different heights and vertical alignments we probably need some more assumptions about what is a neighbor. I will define a neighbor as the closest rectagle to the right with some portion of the rectangle between horizontal lines drawn at the top and bottom of base rectangle. This means there can be ties.
3. What is the scale of the dataset? For now I am assuming it is relatively small. If the dataset is very large I would recommend using the built in [geometry data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and looking into using a [spatial index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017).
4. What do you want in the output, all rectangles in the group or just the first?

Please clarify any details and I will try to update.

Assuming a small dataset, horizontal matches, and returing each 'match' as a single row with a 'left' and 'right' rectangle. Note, if there is a group of three rectangles this will return two rows 1->2 and 2->3. This pattern would continue for a group of N adjacent rectangles with the same attribute type.

Given these assumptions the problem can be divied into a few steps. First, given a rectangle (say rect_0) identify all neighbor(s) to the right (I am going to work left to right). Second identify the closest of those. Third check for matching attributes.

```
-- part 1 find all potential neighbors
with part_1 as (
    select
        a.id as rect_a_id
      , b.id as rect_b_id
      , a.attr as rect_a_attr
      , b.attr as rect_b_attr
      , (b.x-a.x) as dist_right
    from
        dbo.example_rect as a
        inner join dbo.example_rect as b
            on
            a.id<>b.id -- dont compare against self
            and a.x<b.x -- only check things to the 'right' of rect a
            and (a.y+a.height) >b.y -- the top of rect a should be > the bottom of rect b
            and a.y< (b.y+b.height) -- the bottom of rect a should be < the top of rect b
                                    -- if the top of a is greater than the bottom of b AND
                                    -- the bottom of a is less than the top of b then there
                                    -- has to be some overlap
)
-- part 2 find the 'closest' neighbors, note there can be ties
, part_2 as (
    select
        a.rect_a_id
      , a.rect_b_id
      , a.rect_a_attr
      , a.rect_b_attr
      , a.dist_right
    from
        part_1 as a
        inner join (select part_1.rect_a_id, min(part_1.dist_right) as min_dist_right from part_1 group by part_1.rect_a_id) as b
            on
            a.rect_a_id=b.rect_a_id
            and a.dist_right=b.min_dist_right
)
-- part 3 return the 'closest' neighobrs that have the same attribute types, note
-- this could easily be moved up into part 2 but was separated for simplicity
select part_2.rect_a_id, part_2.rect_b_id from part_2 where part_2.rect_a_attr=part_2.rect_b_attr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select objects which create groups with the same attribute as well as single object based on height and weight of the rectangle.

**Query**

```
select *, count(id) over (partition by attr, height, width) same_rectangles from example_rect
```